# Creating a dynamic table in Razor while avoiding green VS validation squiggles

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, razor

Suppose I have a `List` of the following model -

```
public class stock
{
  public string modelNo {get;set;}
  public List<string> serialNumbers {get;set;}
}
```

and I want to display it as a table, something like -

```
Model No  |  Serial Numbers
----------------------------
Model A   |  ABC
          |  DEF
          |  GHI
----------------------------
Model B   |  123
          |  456
----------------------------
```

To display the table I'm using something like the below but I get an annoying green squiggle below the final `</tr>` -

```
<table>
<tr>
  <th> 
    Model No
  </th>
  <th>
    Serial Numbers
  </th>
</tr>      
@foreach (SalesOrderDetail line in Model)
{
  int rowSpan = 1;
  if (line.serialNumbers.Count() != 0)
  {
    rowSpan = line.serialNumbers.Count();
  }
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="@rowSpan">
      @line.modelNo
    </td>
    @{
        int itemNo = 0;
    }
    @foreach (string serial in line.serialNumbers)
    {
      if (itemNo > 0)
      {
        @:<tr>
      }
      <td>
        @serial
      </td>
      {
        itemNo++;
        if (itemNo < rowSpan)
        {
          @:</tr>
        }
      }
    }
    </tr> <- Green squiggle here ("End tag is missing matching start tag")
  }
</table>
```

I know it's a *really* minor annoyance but does anyone know of a way to handle it trivially?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your logic with `if (itemNo > 0)` cannot be understood by the editor at edit time. In order to avoid the validation error you need to refactor this to have one loop and emit the `td` elements inside depending on the loop, something like this:

```
@{
    int itemNo = 0;
}
@foreach (string serial in line.serialNumbers)
{
<tr>
  if (itemNo == 0)
  {
    <td rowspan="@rowSpan">
      @line.modelNo
    </td>
  }
  <td>
    @serial
  </td>
  {
    itemNo++;
  }
</tr>
}
```

Note that this code block is not fully equivalent; it will not render a `tr` if `line.serialNumbers` is empty. However, if this is a requirement, you can still add it separately with an if block, like so (this also fixes the possible `rowspan="0"` bug):

```
@if (rowSpan > 0) {
    @{
        bool first = true;
    }
    @foreach (string serial in line.serialNumbers) {
    <tr>
        @if (first) {
                first = false
        <td rowspan="@rowSpan">
            @line.modelNo
        </td>
        }
        <td>
        @serial
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
} else {
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            @line.modelNo
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```